# How to get the total incoming call duration and total outgoing call duration in Android

Tags: android

How to get the total incoming call duration and total outgoing call duration in Android.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Madan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [android.provider.CallLog.Calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html). With this class you can get the content of the Call Log (incoming, outgoing, missed calls) which contains the duration of every call.

Here is [a tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_querying_and_displaying_the_calllog-t169.html) about it.

Comment: Is there any tutorial to get total number of sent messages and total number of received messages.